# Docker: how to get back to initial directory after issuing a WORKDIR command

Tags: docker

There is no explanation in docker doc or seemingly any builtin variable in docker to find the original working directory where the image is being built. 
I want to run commands on different directories and at some point get back to where i launched docker build from.
Am I missing something obvious?
Thanks.

Dockerfile example:

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /my_folder
RUN command1
WORKDIR ??? // How do i get back to the Dockerfile folder?
RUN command2
```

Comment: Not sure why you need this, can you elaborate?

Comment: you can build many images and stay in the same directory, using `-f, --file=""   ` from the doc of `docker build` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `WORKDIR` directive is really just `cd` for your Dockerfile.

Your original working directory inside the container is `/`.  You can get back there by:

```
WORKDIR /
```

Remember, this is affecting the context of the containerized build environment, and has nothing to do with where your Dockerfile is located.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. I think they could add that in the Docker doc for WORKDIR

Comment: Did something change now ? WORKDIR / takes me to root directory of the image and not to the original folder.

Comment: @Deepthi Nop, WORKDIR act as the "cd" command. Since with Docker you are logged as root by default, you go to the root directory.

Comment: can we use `WORKDIR -` to return to the previous folder?